# Where will my bus be at the Port Authority Bus Terminal in New York?

Tags: buses, tips-and-tricks, new-york-city, greyhound

I am using Greyhound to go from NY to DC. I don't see on my ticket where exactly my bus will be. Is this information on my ticket somewhere or do I just go to Port Authority and ask? This is my first bus trip so I'm a bit nervous.

Answer (score 9):

Your Greyhound will certainly leave from Port Authority in New York, some tickets don't have the door or gate number printed on them, but everything is available at the station. I've done this myself on a few occasions, it's a big station and they've organized it a little like an airport in the sense where they have some panels up with the next departures and their corresponding gates.

Worst case there is always an agent there, either at the ticket counter or by any of the gates, you can ask them they know their routes very well. Just make sure to get there well ahead of time, it's a huge and very confusing place

Comment: Port Authority is a horrible, chaotic place where I had the chance to miss my Jersey bus due to extremely confusing signs starting outside. The building with huge "Authority" letters? That's the Beer Authority pub not the bus station. The bus station is the pharmacy across the street. https://goo.gl/qr8hZ7 It will just get better inside. Leave *plenty* of time for that hellhole.

Comment: Seconding @chx's comment - I live in NYC, I used to commute via the Port Authority regularly, and I would still arrive at the Port Authority early to make sure I ended up at the right gate.

Comment: I arrived early at Port Authority for those reasons, and another: On occasion I was able to board an _earlier_ bus than the one I was scheduled for, simply by being on line early.

Comment: @chx I see you use the word "pharmacy" metaphorically...

Comment: @Bigbio2002 absolutely not, click my link, as you come to this corner you will see a Duane Reade pharmacy, there are no signs I could see of the building being the Port Authority terminal.

Comment: @chx I only know the Duane Reade on the NW corner of 42nd/8th, I rarely approach PABT from the south. I thought you were talking about some of those sketchy "pharmacists" that are out and about in the vicinity. Well, at least if you mistakenly wander into Beer Authority, you can have a PABT Blue Ribbon while you wait for the next bus. Ha ha.

Comment: I have departed from there a few times. There are helpful people everywhere, just dying to tell you where you need to be. Just look like a lost tourist.

Answer (score 4):

Enter at 42nd and 8th. It's the big building with the taxis and sketchy characters standing outside (or if arriving by subway, enter through the direct subway entrance). **Go downstairs** to gates ~**60-90**ish. There are signs labeling it, but I don't recall the exact range listed. After descending the stairs to the correct level, the bus to DC will be somewhere ahead and/or towards the right. If I recall correctly, it should be `Gate #86` or so, but there will be a sign somewhere straight ahead in the vicinity of the stairs with the full listing of Greyhound destinations and gates.

Answer (score 3):

You can find your gate by asking someone from the Greyhound ticket booth or you can use the new touch screen that tells you your gate by searching for your travel id located somewhere on your ticket.